# How to find data/graphs for power and iops

Tags: monitoring

I've used boundary.com for monitoring network usage, data read/write, etc. on a second-to-second basis. I want to put together a demonstration of a few hardware solutions and have a way to present current or average iops, power utilization, and cpu utilization but I'm having difficulty finding which method is best for getting and presenting this data. I know our PDUs can respond to some SNMP calls and the vmware hosts may have some way for measuring iops but I was wondering if there are any solutions which you could recommend?

edit: looking in to Cacti and will modify this, if needed, with specific configuration questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into Cacti, it has a wide range of devices it supports. The initial set up is a little tricky but it will do just about anything you can imagine afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the information, that looks perfect. I'll probably edit this question soon with a more specific configuration question (going to have an EVA array on HP g7 blades, a c3000 and a cs240 all on the same rack and demonstrate a bunch of stuff) Hopefully the config won't be too bad. Thanks again!!!